# 1st did Dataflow import which does not do custom options; Did a regular import after that few times - now have duplicate custom options

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, importexport, dataflow, magento-1.9.4.0

> Magento 1.9.1 --) Magento 1.9.4

It's 2019 so you would think migrating All products from Magento 1.9.1 to Magento 1.9.4 would be smooth sailing right? I would expect to click Export on one system, take the file and Import it into 1.9.4. Instead:

*- there were tons of Error messages when trying to do a regular Export/Import so I decided to do the Dataflow Export/Import instead...*

That worked except for it did not transfer any custom options (colors, sizes etc.). So I decided to do a regular export and import of just the SKU and the custom options (because it gave Errors about websites, categories - I removed those columns from the CSV file).

Then it seemed all ready to go - after I cleared all the Errors and Magento says the file could be imported - it just showed the circle going around all the time and says **Please wait**. It never finished. I contacted the hosting company and they said it's not their problem and increasing the time-out will not help etc. and told me to contact a Magento developer. Then I split the file up into many - sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not.

Finally, ***I managed to get the custom options in but they are all duplicated like 10 times*** (looks like the number of times I tried the regular import).

**What is my best plan going forward? Can I just delete all Products and start the process again and this time be careful only to import the specific part of a file once? Are there any undesired consequences to deleting 1000 products? Would it be better to do a full restore of the Magento 1.9.4? Any better way to do this?**